# Scatter Plot from pandas table in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

New student to python and struggling with a task at the moment. I'm trying to publish a scatter plot from some data in a pandas table and can't seem to work it out.

Here is a sample of my data set:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'housing_age': [14, 11, 3, 4],
        'total_rooms': [25135, 32627, 39320, 37937],
        'total_bedrooms': [4819, 6445, 6210, 5471],
        'population': [35682, 28566, 16305, 16122]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I'm trying to draw a scatter plot on the data in housing_age, but having some difficult figuring it out.

Initially tried for x axis to be 'housing_data' and the y axis to be a count of housing data, but couldn't get the code to work. Then read somewhere that x-axis should be variable, and y-axis should be constant, so tried this code:

```
x='housing_data'
y=[0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55]
plt.scatter(x,y)
ax.set_xlabel("Number of buildings")
ax.set_ylabel("Age of buildings")
```

but get this error:
ValueError: x and y must be the same size

Note - the data in 'housing_data' ranges from 1-53 years.

I imagine this should be a pretty easy thing, but for some reason I can't figure it out.

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: `x` and `y` need to be numerical lists/arrays of the same length.  Have you gone to the matplotlib website and looked at the "gallery" which has TONS of sample code?

Comment: And if you are looking to plot the "count of things" that is a *histogram* not a scatter plot.  In that case, you just need a single vector of values.  Again, look at the matplotlib site in the gallery or documents on how to pretty it up.

Comment: In the future, to add information, [edit] the question. Aside from that, it's not clear what you're trying to plot. Review [`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html), which has links to examples at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks @AirSquid - reading through now. Trying to represent it another way at the moment, where x = house_age and y = house_suburb. Both data sets are complete with no zero fields. One is numerical and one is string. 

my code is:
    x=data['housing_data']
    y=data['ocean_proximity']
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    ax.set_xlabel("Number of buildings")
    ax.set_ylabel("Suburb of buildings")

I've got error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

I thought that happened with 0 value data? I'm a bit lost sorry....

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are starting so confusion is common. Please bear with me.

From your description, it looks like you swapped `x` and `y`:

```
# x is the categories: 0-5 yrs, 5-10 yrs, ...
x = [0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55]

# y is the number of observations in each category
# I just assigned it some random numbers
y = [78, 31, 7, 58, 88, 43, 47, 87, 91, 87, 36, 78]

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.set_title('Housing Data')
```

[image]

Generally, if you have a list of observations and you want to count them across a number of categories, it's called a **histogram**. pandas has many convenient functions to give you a quick look at the data. The one of interest for this question is `hist` - create a histogram:

```
# A series of 100 random buildings whose age is between 1 and 55 (inclusive)
buildings = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, 55, 100))

# Make a histogram with 10 bins
buildings.hist(bins=10)

# The edges of those bins were determined automatically so they appear a bit weird:
pd.cut(buildings, bins=10)

0     (22.8, 28.0]
1      (7.2, 12.4]
2     (33.2, 38.4]
3     (38.4, 43.6]
4     (48.8, 54.0]
          ...     
95    (48.8, 54.0]
96    (22.8, 28.0]
97    (12.4, 17.6]
98    (43.6, 48.8]
99    (1.948, 7.2]
```

[image]

You can also set the bins explicitly: 0-5, 5-10, ..., 50-55

```
buildings.hist(bins=range(0,60,5))

# Then the edges are no longer random
pd.cut(buildings, bins=range(0,60,5))
0     (25, 30]
1      (5, 10]
2     (30, 35]
3     (40, 45]
4     (45, 50]
        ...   
95    (45, 50]
96    (25, 30]
97    (15, 20]
98    (40, 45]
99      (0, 5]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Code - this is a great walk through. Really appreciate your help.

If I'm trying to feed in 2 existing data sets from a pandas table, do you know how I get this to work? I thought this might work:

x=df['housing_age']
y=df['suburb']
plt.scatter(x,y)

But I'm getting a NoneType error

Comment: For scatter plot, matplotlib expect 2 array of numbers: one represent the x coordinates, the other represents the y coordinates. It will not work if either array is non-numeric